# Power shell - Check files line by line for /x00 and replace "" and save the checked file in different folder

Tags: powershell

I would like to ask you, how to check the all files in folder for `/x00`. Replace `/x00` with `nothing` and save the checked files in different folder with the same fail name.

Here is the code only for one file:

```
(Get-Content "C:\source\filename.dat") -replace "\x00", "" |
    Set-Content "C:\temp\filename.dat"
```

Comment: Is `\x00` a literal string or an escape sequence?

Comment: If i understand right \x00 is  literal string. 
For example sometimes the program save me the file like this 5 0 1 8 4 5 1 _ 2 0 9 4 4 . And i wont to remove this spece between the nummbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment of removing space between the outputs (although this method will remove ALL whitespace in the file):

```
#Requires -Version 4
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\dat' -PipelineVariable 'f' |
    ForEach-Object {
        (Get-Content -Path $f.FullName) -replace '\s' |
            Set-Content -Path ('C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\' + $f.Name)
    }
```

---

If you're specifically looking for the `\x00` hex character (`NUL`), here's a v2 compatible snippet:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path
ForEach ($File in $Files)
{
    (Get-Content -Path $File.FullName) -replace '\s' -replace "`0" |
        Set-Content -Path ('C:\Temp\' + $File.Name)
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that i have meny files with a diferent names every  time in the folder. And I need a script to check the all filles and save them in another folder.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov So your problem is you need to rename all the files in a directory?

Comment: I dont wont to rename the files. Just I wont to remove the /x00 from content of the file and save the check file in the another folder with the same filename.

Comment: this is the content of bad file:5 0 1 8 4 5 1 _ 2 0 9 4 4 _ P a l l e t 1
after the script it must be 5018451_20944_Pallet1

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnItI_64vvrLgcIDceWLndiCkd4q8Q hire you can see the bad file. and I wont to remove this " " from it.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov OK, so the whitespace is a NUL `\x00` binary character then?  This will probably involve reading the file bytes at this point.

Comment: TheIncorrigible1 yes your script works, but i wont to do it for the all files in the folder. Not for only one.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov OK, I think I understand your ask now.  Look at my updated edit

Comment: If my solution solved your question, kindly upvote & mark it as the answer for future searchers @GeorgiAngelov

Answer (score 0):

This is the script in Python :

```
import os
source_path = "C:\\Users\\georgi\\Desktop\\dat\\"
target_path = "C:\\Users\\georgi\\Desktop\\5\\"
for source in os.listdir(source_path):
  with open(source_path + source, 'r') as s, open(target_path + source, 'a') as t:
    for line in s:
      t.write(line.replace('\x00', '').replace(' ',''))
```

I hope it helps you to understand what I want.